# Developing in eclipse without using any git eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I've been using SVN and Eclipse for development for a while, and love the strong integration between the two. However I'm now switching over to git, and understand that while the git Eclipse plugins like EGit have gotten better, they're still not as good as SVN plugins for Eclipse. (For example, there's still no submodule support, and I plan to use submodules extensively.)

I'm wondering, are there any of you who use Eclipse for development on a git project but don't use the Eclipse plugin? Meaning, you either use another git GUI client (I'm on Linux) or do everything from the command line. If so, how does this work for you?

Is it a big pain not to be able to see directly in Eclipse which files are not synchronized with the repository, etc, or is that not such a big deal? Or can I still use EGit just to see which files have changed, but make all commits and do all operations from the command line or another GUI client? If so, could anyone who's doing that describe what such a workflow might look like.

Is there any risk or problems involved with accessing one repository from multiple clients, such as command line, EGit, and multiple git GUI clients - like could it cause repository corruption because they could all change metadata at the same time? Or is it perfectly safe?

With SVN everything was simple - I never needed the command line or another GUI client for anything. Everything was possible within Eclipse. But now I'm concerned about what to expect because I really don't know how this will change my development style or if it's doable. Certainly with git being such a popular VCS and Eclipse being such a popular IDE, there are many who use both together and who can describe for me how they use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EGit will play fairly well with the command line git tool.  I use both on linux.  It's still worth installing EGit, I think, and then at least you see the status of your projects.

Sometimes you have to use F5-Refresh to refresh EGit's view of your repo, but EGit already works at refreshing the workspace with local file changes, so it doesn't come up that often.

The only other suggestion that I have is that you wouldn't want multiple workspaces to point to the same git repo.  That can cause confusion.

Comment: +1. I’m using the command line only with Eclipse and never had any problems. Using the CLI gives me access to all functions of Git, so that’s just the best solution in my opinion. I did use EGit for showing the status together with the CLI before on a different machine, and that worked just fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak specifically for git, but I used to do something very similar with SVN, and I can't see any issues with doing this.  Additionally, at least with SVN and Subclipse, Subclipse worked with the SVN working copy just as any other SVN client would.  There are several operations that I still use the svn command-line tool for against the same projects I'm working on Eclipse.  This includes things like "svn status", as well as doing batch updates of SVN properties across files (something Subclipse doesn't currently support).  Other than needing to use F5 in Eclipse to perform an occasional refresh, I've never had any issues with this.

I've done very similar things with several other source control systems, and never had any issues.  Especially if you just use an external client and don't worry about source control integration into Eclipse for git, I can't see that you'd have any problems, as Eclipse won't attempt to share any concern with this.  I would also reommend trying EGit, as I'm guessing it will work very similar to Subclipse and not cause any significant issues.  (I hope to do this soon myself.)

In terms of the workflow, in many cases - at least for an experienced developer, this should work better in some cases.  In Eclipse, I often find myself switching between the Package Explorer and Navigator views to see all the files that Eclipse hides or translates by default in the Package Explorer view.  Switching between Eclipse and another client really doesn't work any differently.